# Python Matrix Output to Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, numpy

I'm trying to output a matrix with 4 rows (1st row is header) and over 6000 columns. Each column header is a word from different text documents (rows 1-3). I want to export it to excel so I can easily filter the top 10 words with highest frequency. I get no error, but nothing shows up in the excel file. Where am I going wrong?

```
np.savetxt('file.csv', matrix_TF, delimiter = ',', newline = '\n', encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Is the file written ?

Comment: " I want to export it to excel so I can easily filter the top 10 words with highest frequency. " you can do that pretty easily using Python too...

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path like "/tmp/file.csv"?

Comment: @PauloScardine Would that help?

Comment: Yeah I couldn't figure out how to do it in python so I figured it would be faster to just export it to excel?

Comment: @Nabin the way I hunt a bug is taking by things out of the way. Perhaps it is writing the file, just not where the OP is expecting so giving an absolute path would confirm this or rule it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see from your response to another suggestion you would prefer doing this in Python. It's very possible. Check out the *collections* methods [linkd here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

The first section, 8.3.1, shows an example of the most common words found in *Hamlet*

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter()

l1 = [['a','b','c','d','e','e','e'],['a','a','a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','c','c','c','d','e']]

x = 0
for n in l1:
    x += 1
    for tf in n:
        cnt[tf] += 1
    print cnt
    cnt = Counter()
```

Comment: I have no issue getting the top 10 words from the original text. My concern is with this term frequency matrix (matrix_TF). I need to see this matrix in excel because it contains 3 rows (all different text documents).

Comment: You have three text documents. I'm guessing from your question you've created a term frequency matrix, which is a list of header information, document1, document2, and document3. You can still try to use collections. Check out the updated code snippet in my answer.